# Do require(s) in multiple files create separate instances or do they use only one?

Tags: lua

Lets say that in file1 we have this:

```
local fileinstance = require("required_file")
```

This should load the file and create an instance of it defined as fileinstance. If in another file, file2, we do the same thing:

```
local fileinstance = require("required_file")
```

Will this create a whole new active instance of "required_file" or will it default to the previous one? The reason I ask this is because I have a variable in "required_file" that I want to be set, and stay the same across all other files that require it without the variable being reset to the default

Comment: `require` will remember first result, no new instance will be created on the second invocation.

Comment: Perfect! Thats the kind of news I needed today. Thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you [modify `package.loaded`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-package.loaded) or otherwise [change `require`'s machinery](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-require), it will not load the same module more than once. It will simply produce the return value of the module that it loaded.

Comment: Your second link is missing (and I'm not sure what you wanted to link or else I'd have edited it in.)

Comment: @nobody: Fixed.